# Can anything be learned about a probability distribution *directly* from its characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Some preliminaries: I *know* that one can take the inverse Fourier transform to get back the pdf...that is not what I am after. My question is whether the characteristic function, qua function, tells us anything about the underlying random variable.

As an example: The moment generating function can be *directly* used in Chernoff's Lemma:

$$P(X\geq0)\leq MGF_{X}(t),\; \forall t$$

Is there anything that can be similarly done with a Characteristic Function? Does it's complex modulus or absolute square have any meaning? Can we directly interpret its real or complex parts separately?

From the little I have used the Characteristic Function, it seems to be used for showing convergence in distribution, and relies simply upon *recognizing* the forms of various characteristic equations. However, this narrow view is likely just from inexperience. I would be happy to have my view expanded :-)

Comment: One example: Using the Paley Wiener theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz.27s_Paley.E2.80.93Wiener_theorem), one can decide by looking at the (unique, if it exists) holomorphic extension of the characteristic function whether the probability distribution has compact support.

Comment: The characteristic function can be used to estimate tails, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq R)$$ or to prove the existence of moments. Moreover, there are also several statements which characterize the range of $X$ (e.g. if there exists $\xi_0 \neq 0$ such that $|\phi_X(\xi_0)|=1$, then $X(\Omega)$ has a lattice structure.)

Comment: @PhoemueX, saz: Thanks to both of you...very interesting results.!!

Comment: @saz Could you please provide some reference as to the meaning of $X(\Omega)$ and its lattice structure?

Comment: @zoli seems like it means that the spacing between values of the function $X(\omega)$ are separated by integral values of some value $r$.

Comment: @zoli It means that there exist numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$X(\omega) \in \{a+b \cdot j; j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can derive from the inversion formula the bound 
$$\mathbb P\{ |X|\geqslant 2/\delta \}\leqslant \delta^{-1}\int_{-\delta}^\delta (1-\varphi_X(s))\mathrm ds.$$

Comment: This is pretty cool. Isn't $\varphi$ complex valued? How do you get it to be real valued?

Comment: The interval of integration is symmetric.

Comment: I see. My complex analysis is quite rusty...